# Como imprimir dados de um array

Tags: php

Caros, tenho um formulário que envia dados através do método `$_POST`, verifico se os dados estão setados `$_POST['nome_campo']`; e através do `foreach()`, carrego o array `$_POST` dentro de uma variável!
Apos realizar o `foreach()` gostaria de saber como faço para imprimir cada valor do array em outro formulário!?

```
<?php       

   if( isset($_POST)){         

        $txtQtdFunc = $_POST['txtQtdFunc'];

        //print_r($_POST);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $txtQtdFunc; $i++) {

            //Recebe todos os campos e registros do form

            foreach($_POST as $nome_campo => $valor){

               echo $strMsg = $valor ."<br>";     

           }//fim foreach    
  }//fim isset            

?>
```

Comment: Creio que "$_POST" ta faltando a variável, ali na hora do foreach.

Comment: Seria importante você postar também seu formulário `HTML` para que possamos verificar como está sendo enviando as informações, pois `name = "txtQtdFunc"`, não é uma boa escolha. Não dá para saber se é um texto, um numero ou alguma dado do Funcionário. Escrever nomes simples e objetivos dentro de sua aplicação, torna mais fácil o entendimento e o comportamento da sua aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Há um erro na linha:

> ```
> if(isset($_POST)) {
> ```

Conforme a documentação da função `isset`:

> Verifica se a variável é definida.
>
> Se a variável for destruída com `unset()`, ela não existirá mais.
>   `isset()` retornará FALSE se for usada em uma variável com o valor NULL.
>   Lembrando que no PHP um byte NULL (`\0`) é diferente da constante
>   NULL.

A variável `$_POST` sempre é iniciada. Dessa forma, essa condição está sendo mal utilizada.

Referente a descrição do seu problema, não ficou muito claro, mas elaborei uma possível solução:

```
<?php       
  if(isset($_POST['txtQtdFunc'])) { // Valor que deve vir via post
    $txtQtdFunc = $_POST['txtQtdFunc'];

    // Imprimir valores
    foreach($_POST as $chave => $valor) {
      echo "$chave - $valor"; // Imprimirá todas as chaves e seus respectivos valores
    }
  }
?>
```

Dessa forma, todos os valores enviados via `post` serão mostrados.

Comment: Ok,dessa forma funcionou! Agora eu gostaria de saber como faço para imprimir os valores da $valor em um input no formulário html

Answer (score -2):

Seria algo assim?

```
<?php

$arr = array(
  0 => 10,
  1 => 20,
  2 => 30,
  3 => 40,

);

foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="dados[]" id="" value="<?php echo $v;?             >">
       </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

Caso não seja formata melhor a dúvida.